# Python enqueue tasks and get results in order

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, task-queue

I would like to have multiple threads performing tasks, but I would also like to get the results in order.

Take a simple sample code:

```
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time


class TaskQueue(queue.Queue):
    def __init__(self, num_workers=1):
        queue.Queue.__init__(self)
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.start_workers()

    def add_task(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        args = args or ()
        kwargs = kwargs or {}
        self.put((task, args, kwargs))

    def start_workers(self):
        for i in range(self.num_workers):
            t = Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            ##tupl = self.get()  # REMOVED
            item, args, kwargs = self.get()
            item(*args, **kwargs)
            self.task_done()


def task(task_num, sleep_time):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print("Task #{} sleeping {}".format(task_num, sleep_time))

q = TaskQueue(num_workers=2)

for t, s in zip([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]):
    q.add_task(task, t, s)

q.join()  # block until all tasks are done
print("All Done!!")
```

Where I am adding tasks, with associated task number and each taking different execution time (sleeps).

I have three issues/questions.

<s>1) I am not even getting all the outputs (without even considering the order).  Currently I am just getting the output:</s>

```
   Task #4 sleeping 6
   Task #2 sleeping 8
   Task #6 sleeping 4
   Task #8 sleeping 2
```

Seems I am not getting the odd tasks, maybe everything coming from the other worker.  Why is that and how can I get them?

2. The program just hangs afterwards.  I am assuming since the worker blocks until it gets something from the queue.  And if the queue is empty, just waits forever.  How can I update it so it will quit or hit "All Done!!" once there is no more tasks in the queue.
3. How can I have it print the tasks in order?  Basically I want the results to be:

   ```
   Task #1 sleeping 9
   Task #2 sleeping 8
   Task #3 sleeping 7
   Task #4 sleeping 6
   Task #5 sleeping 5
   Task #6 sleeping 4
   Task #7 sleeping 3
   Task #8 sleeping 2
   Task #9 sleeping 1
   ```

Also assume the task results are quite large and the number of tasks itself is a lot, thus I dont really want to have them all saved in memory then do some ordering. I should know the number of tasks added into the queue, and would just like to utilize those on what to print first.  Saving some in memory temporarily is acceptable.  I know in the current example you kind of have to save some first, since the first task takes the longest.  You can assume that the execution time (or sleep in this case) will be random per tasks.

Currently using Python 3.7

---EDIT---

Removing `tupl = self.get()` from the above code solved question #1 and #2.  Thus only question #3 is remaining.  Any ideas/solution are welcome

Comment: There is no way to adjust the order in which they are printing since the print statement is happening within your asynchronous threads. You can, however, get results from your threads and then print them in order by the task assignment. Is that what you would like help with?

Comment: Your 3rd question currently sounds like you want your asynchronous code to run synchronously, which defeats the point. Just run the code synchronously. Can you clarify?

Comment: @deseuler Yes it does sound like I want it to run synchronously, but I dont.  Running it synchronously will take longer.  Lets take an example where we have 10 tasks, each running 10 seconds.  If I were to run them all synchronously, then it will take 100 seconds to complete.  If I have 2 threads running, then I can have the results in half the time (~50 seconds).  That is what I want.  Maybe I will need 2 queues, one for the tasks and one for the results.  Results queue may just have the objects as results, then its the main thread managing which ones to print first or something like that.

Comment: Yes, do that.  Note you must be prepared to store all the results — memory, filesystem, whatever — to sort them.  Worst case:  the very first task is the last to complete.  Alternatively, use the [`ThreadPoolExecutor.map()` from `concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: I believe he is trying to have some control over execution of non time consuming actions within threads. Which after thinking about it, seems possible by passing down a custom linked list. `concurrent.futures.Executor` also seems promising.

Comment: I was able to make it work using 2 queues (jobs, results).  And the main thread reads the the results and since the expected results is based on a sequence of the tasks (1,2,3...).  If anything is received out of order, its saved to a dictionary temporarily then can be printed out and deleted once the appropriate task is hit

Comment: @user1179317 Can you post the answer to the question?

Comment: Ok will do.  I'll be posting another question that I encountered

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to my question.  Using two queues (for the jobs and for the results).  Answers are extracted from the results queue and saved in a dictionary.  They are printed out in order and deleted accordingly.

Taking 23 seconds for 2 workers, where 1 worker or just synchronous execution takes 45 seconds:

```
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time
import datetime

class TaskQueue():
    def __init__(self, num_workers=1):
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.total_num_jobs = 0
        self.jobs_completed = 0
        self.answers_sent = 0
        self.jobs = queue.Queue()
        self.results = queue.Queue()
        self.start_workers()

    def add_task(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        args = args or ()
        kwargs = kwargs or {}
        self.total_num_jobs += 1
        self.jobs.put((task, args, kwargs))

    def start_workers(self):
        for i in range(self.num_workers):
            t = Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            item, args, kwargs = self.jobs.get()
            item(*args, **kwargs)
            self.jobs_completed += 1
            self.jobs.task_done()

    def get_answers(self):
        while self.answers_sent < self.total_num_jobs or self.jobs_completed == 0:
            yield self.results.get()
            self.answers_sent += 1
            self.results.task_done()


def task(task_num, sleep_time, q):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    ans = "Task #{} sleeping {}".format(task_num, sleep_time)
    q.put((task_num, ans))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    h = TaskQueue(num_workers=2)
    q = h.results
    answers = {}
    curr_task = 1

    for t, s in zip([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]):
        h.add_task(task, t, s, q)

    for task_num, ans in h.get_answers():
        answers[task_num] = ans
        if curr_task in answers:
            print(answers[curr_task])
            del answers[curr_task]
            curr_task += 1

    # Print remaining items (if any)
    for k, v in sorted(answers.items()):
        print(v)

    h.jobs.join()  # block until all tasks are done

    print("All done")
    print("Total Execution: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - start))
```