# Python enqueue tasks and get results in order (multiprocess)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, task-queue

I asked the question before [enqueue tasks and get results in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67627400/python-enqueue-tasks-and-get-results-in-order) and I developed an answer using multi-threading.  Due to some performance issues (in my real scenario -- not seen in this simple example), I would like to try using multi-processing instead.  Unfortunately I am unable to come up with a working solution.  For quick reference here's the working solution for multithreading:

```
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time
import datetime

class TaskQueue():
    def __init__(self, num_workers=1):
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.total_num_jobs = 0
        self.jobs_completed = 0
        self.answers_sent = 0
        self.jobs = queue.Queue()
        self.results = queue.Queue()
        self.start_workers()

    def add_task(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        args = args or ()
        kwargs = kwargs or {}
        self.total_num_jobs += 1
        self.jobs.put((task, args, kwargs))

    def start_workers(self):
        for i in range(self.num_workers):
            t = Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            item, args, kwargs = self.jobs.get()
            item(*args, **kwargs)
            self.jobs_completed += 1
            self.jobs.task_done()

    def get_answers(self):
        while self.answers_sent < self.total_num_jobs or self.jobs_completed == 0:
            yield self.results.get()
            self.answers_sent += 1
            self.results.task_done()


def task(task_num, sleep_time, q):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    ans = "Task #{} sleeping {}".format(task_num, sleep_time)
    q.put((task_num, ans))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    h = TaskQueue(num_workers=2)
    q = h.results
    answers = {}
    curr_task = 1

    for t, s in zip([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]):
        h.add_task(task, t, s, q)

    for task_num, ans in h.get_answers():
        answers[task_num] = ans
        if curr_task in answers:
            print(answers[curr_task])
            del answers[curr_task]
            curr_task += 1

    # Print remaining items (if any)
    for k, v in sorted(answers.items()):
        print(v)

    h.jobs.join()  # block until all tasks are done

    print("All done")
    print("Total Execution: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - start))
```

Desired output:

```
Task #1 sleeping 9
Task #2 sleeping 8
Task #3 sleeping 7
Task #4 sleeping 6
Task #5 sleeping 5
Task #6 sleeping 4
Task #7 sleeping 3
Task #8 sleeping 2
Task #9 sleeping 1
All done
```

Which takes 23 seconds only when its multithreaded, but takes 45 seconds if the job is performed synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

you can use asycnio to make your program faster.
However it is difficult to understand Asyncio but after some experience it can be very beneficial.

[Area Covered by Asyncio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGmAL.png)

Here is an example of asyncio code.

```py
import time
import asyncio

async def main_process(sleepTime):
    await asyncio.sleep(sleepTime)
    print("Done sleep for",sleepTime)
    return sleepTime
    
async def main():
    startTime = time.perf_counter()
    tasks = []
    for sleepTime in [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(main_process(sleepTime))
        tasks.append(task)
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    endTime = time.perf_counter()
    print('Total Time taken',endTime-startTime)
    print("these are the responses gathered",responses)
    
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

At above asyncio.gather have also gather all the responses in the same order.

This will give following output:

```py
Done sleep for 1
Done sleep for 2
Done sleep for 3
Done sleep for 4
Done sleep for 5
Done sleep for 6
Done sleep for 7
Done sleep for 8
Done sleep for 9
Total Time taken 9.015136200000143
these are the responses gathered [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

It might give you some idea

Comment: This doesnt really give me the solution I want, but definitely worth taking note of.  Might be useful in the future. Thanks

Comment: Actually I used the above method to tackle with problem which you are trying to solve.
In my scenario I had to gather request first then do the processing tasks.
For this I awaited for the main request task and other were carried out accordingly.

Comment: In asyncio you can gather more then one task as I mentioned asyncio.gather so we can make 2 or more asyncio.gather at same time and it will also carry out other asyncio.gather task  at the same time.
If you need more explanation I can update my code so It will give you an idea that how can you achieve what you want using asyncio

Comment: No it does not do what I wanted to solve.  If you update your code with "for sleepTime in [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:", you will get the lowest sleep first.  My example should get the longest one first.  Basically it should print them out in order of the job added to the queue.  See desired output

Comment: Oh I think I know what you are trying to say.  You are saying this is just a sample, but not really a solution to my problem.  I need to do further updates to your answer to make it work for my specific problem.

Comment: Actuallly you can achieve that let me update my answer

Comment: When all the tasks have been carried out they are displayed in the same order in which they are added.

Comment: Ah i see. That does kinda work, based on my question.  Though, I guess I didnt really ask my question too clearly.  Maybe I'll just ask a different question.